# Expanding a dynamic memory block as needed

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to assign data to a block of memory but I don't know what's the size which I need.
For example, the following is just a simple example which illustrates the purpose:

```
char *str = (char*)malloc(2);
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    str[i] = i;
    realloc(str, strlen(str) + 1);
}
printf("%s\n", str);
```

The previous code prints unknown symbols like the following:

[image]

**What is the problem, then?**

Comment: `malloc` allocate memory but not initialize to `zero` so you need to initialize to zero something like this `memset(str,0, sizeof(char) * 2);`

Comment: Codes 1 to 9 are Control-A through Control-I.  Control-H is backspace; Control-I is tab; Control-G is bell.  What do you expect to see?  (You also have the problem that the data is not null terminated when you start off.  You never set `str[0]` to any known value.)  And reallocating one more byte is slow if you add more than a few characters (more than 50, say, but that's a guess, not a measured value) — don't do it.

Comment: @ThiruShetty: a runtime error occurs when writing this line `memset(str,0, sizeof(char) * 2);`.

Comment: @LionKing this is after you allocate memory with `malloc` not for `realloc`

Comment: @ThiruShetty: Yes, that what I exactly did;

Comment: @LionKing i think `malloc` failed allocate memory as requested, need to check return address of `malloc` shouldn't be `NULL`

Comment: @ThiruShetty: No, `malloc` has allocated memory and returned an address. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allocating memory, that's OK. You are writing a character inside the
limits, that's OK too. But then you use `strlen`, that's not OK, because
`strlen` expects a valid string, you are not passing string.

In C a string is just a sequence of characters that ends with the
`'\0'`-terminating byte. You are not doing that, so `strlen` will go beyond the
limit until it finds the `'\0'`-terminating byte and this is undefined
behaviour.

Also `realloc` *might* change the memory location when expanding the memory. You
are not accounting for that. If `realloc` returns a different pointer, the old
location is invalid and the next `realloc` call will yield undefined behaviour.

The way you are filling the data, you don't even need the `strlen` call, `i`
gives you that information already.

To fix your code:

```
char *str = calloc(2, 1);
if(str == NULL)
{
    // error handling
    // do not continue
    return;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    str[i] = i + 1 + '0';
    str[i+1] = 0; // making sure you have a valid c-string

    char *tmp = realloc(str, strlen(str) + 2);
    if(tmp == NULL)
    {
        // error handling,
        // do not continue
        free(str);
        return;
    }

    // making sure that str points to the new location
    // if realloc returned a different pointer
    str = tmp;
}

printf("%s\n", str);
free(str);
```

You should always check for the return value of `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`.
Also the `realloc` should be `strlen(str) + 2`. The `+2` because you want to add
a new character and you have to have space for the `'\0'`-terminating byte.

Note that for the first allocation I used `calloc`, because `calloc` also sets
the allocated memory to 0, great for initialization. But regardless of that, you
should set the `'\0'`-terminating byte **every** time you add a new character
(`str[i+1] = 0;` line). I also store the value `i + '0'`, which is most probably
what you want. `1 != '1'`, because the character `'1'` has the value 49, not 1.
See: [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

I've changed the `str[i] = i + '0';` to `str[i] = i + 1 + '0';`, because it
seems that you want the string to start with a `'1'`, not a `'0'`.

Also never forget to free the memory you've allocated. You can free the memory
at the end of the program or better still, when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the following point, why you added `0` after `i` here, `i + '0'`, and what if `i` starts by 1, not 0 in the loop `for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)`?

Comment: Because the value 1 and it's character representation `'1'` are not the same. The values of the character representations are determined by the values of the ASCII table (click the link in the answer). You probably want the character representation of 1 in your string. That's why the `+ '0'`.

Comment: Is it possible to modify your code to make `i` starts by 1 instead of 0?

Comment: @LionKing I've made an update of my code that reflects your wish that the string starts with `'1'` and not `'0'`.

Comment: @LionKing my bad. That's because when you do a loop like: `for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)`, you are looping 11 times. You have to change to `for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)`. In the ASCII table, the next character after `'9'` is `':'`, that's why it was added to the list. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

*What is the problem, then?*

very simple, the values in `i` are
0x00000000
0x00000001
...
0x00000009

(which do not fit into a char)

and those values are not part of the 'printable' ascii character set.

Suggest adding `0` (0x30) to each of the values as they are assigned to the array.

Also, suggest casting the `int` `i` to `(char)` at each assignment

the values in the array do not make a 'string' as there is no terminating NUL (0x00) byte.

Following edited for the comment from lion king

Suggest writing the code similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    char *str = malloc(2);   // do not 'cast' the returned value
    if( !str )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" ); // output enclosed text and reason
                                   // system thinks the 'malloc` failed
                                   // to `stderr`
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < MAX_CHARS; i++) 
    {
        str[i] = (char)('0' + i);
        char *temp = realloc(str, i+3);  // assign to temp variable
                                         // and check if successful
                                         // to avoid causing a memory
                                         // leak when it fails
        if( !temp )
        {
            perror( "realloc failed" );
            free( str );  // cleanup
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, realloc successful

        str = temp;   // update the target variable
    }

    // terminate the string
    str[ i ] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", str);

    free( str );  // cleanup

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quote: I want to assign data to a block of memory **but I don't know what's the size which I need**. You defined a const  `MAX_CHARS 10`, And it's supposed I do not know the size or length of the data. Note that loop is just for filling.